# Proving the pre-image of this set

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory

> Question:
>   Let $f: \left ( X,d \right )\rightarrow \left ( Y,e \right )$ be a map between metric spaces.
>   Let $U\subset X$ and let $V \subseteq Y.$
>
> Show that if $V'\subseteq V$ then $f^{-1}\left ( V' \right )\subseteq f^{-1}\left ( V \right ).$

By the definition of pre-image:

$f^{-1}\left ( V' \right )=\left \{ y \in Y \mid f\left ( y \right ) \in V'\right \}.$

Useful hints are appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mistake has been corrected.

Comment: Isnt' it obvious? If $f(y) \in V'$, then $f(y) \in V$, and this completes the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will show that any element $x\in f^{-1}\left ( V' \right )$ is also an element of $f^{-1}\left ( V \right )$.

Let $x\in f^{-1}\left ( V' \right )$ then, by definition of preimage, there is $y\in V'$ such that $f(x)=y$.

Now $V'\subseteq V$ implies that $y\in V$ and therefore $x\in f^{-1}\left ( V \right )$.

Answer (score 1):

$$f^{-1}(V')=\{x\in X\mid f(x)\in V'\}.$$

Since $V'\subset V$,  $$f(x)\in V'\implies f(x)\in V,$$
and thus,
$$\{x\in X\mid f(x)\in V'\}\subset \{x\in X\mid f(x)\in V\}.$$